# nabla operator: is it standard?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-operators

I would like to know what does it mean $$\nabla f(t,\ldots,t)$$ on the page 554 $(4.3)$ [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~raumann/pdf/Recent%20Developments%20in%20the%20Theory.pdf).

Comment: [Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)

Comment: Of course the curious thing is that the $t$ is repeated on the arguments...

Comment: @wpkzz It is fine for me, though.

Comment: I would say gradient also, if there is no other specification on the paper (I do not see one, so...)

Comment: there the notation $f(t,\ldots ,t)$ seems to represent a function $f:\Bbb R ^n\to \Bbb R $ composed by the function $h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R ^n,\, t\mapsto (t,\ldots ,t)$, so $f(t,\ldots ,t)=f\circ h$ is a function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $, and the integrand (the expression appear inside of an integral in the paper) seems to be the vector-valued function $\nabla f\circ h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R ^n$, where $\nabla$ is the gradient